# Xamarin iOS App. Resign with Distribution Profile. Error: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

We have a Xamarin IOS app which is already in App store & it was completely developed by another team. Right now we are trying to modify the app by adding a custom URL scheme and updated the app version. We have signed this app using a development profile and tested in couple of test devices as well. After testing we provide the ipa to another team who is doing the resign and publish using Distribution profile and certificate . While uploading the resigned app we are getting an error "ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc or a development certificate."

Answer (score 1):

Something with your re-signing is not correct.  Try running the following command on the re-signed binary and verify if you get any more details as to what is the problem:

```
codesign -dvvv --no-strict --verify old/Payload/iPhoneApp1.app
```

Also, you mention that you provide the ipa for re-signing to another team for publishing.  You're not providing the ipa that was originally signed to development / ad hoc distribution, are you?  I do not believe you should take a development build and then re-sign it with the distribution cert. I'm pretty sure your entitlements will be messed up.

For app store distribution, I would do a distribution build to an IPA, then send that file to the other team for re-signing and publishing.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when your app has international characters in the app name.